# DynamicData: ObservableCollection.AsObservableChangeSet().Filter().Bind(): BindingList not updated automatically when item added to source collection

Tags: c#, datagridview, observablecollection, dynamic-data, bindinglist

I using DynamicData and have following code:

```
ObservableCollection<Item> sourceCollection = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
BindingList<Item> bl = new BindingList<Item>();

os.AsObservableChangeSet().Filter(x => x.SomeProperty > 15).Bind(bl).Subscribe();

someDataGridView.DataSource = bl;
```

Problem: DataGridView no automatically added item when it happens with source ObservableCollection .

Answer (score 2):

I got burned on this too. There are two methods with remarkably similar names. `AsObservableChangeSet` and `ToObservableChangeSet`. The first one works with `IEnumerable` interface and doesn't react to collection changes. It's only useful on non-changing collections, that you want to listen to changes of its items.
You want to use the other, that works on `ObservableCollection` type - `ToObservableChangeSet`.